# how to store on click appended html in to client side cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to append some data on run time..

now I have to store this appended data into client side Cookies.

Any suggestion much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

here is the code and fiddle URL:

```
$('#add').on('click', function(){
    var inputHTML = $('#inputName').val();
    $('<li>'+inputHTML+'</li>').appendTo('#inputBox > ul');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ft26u/12/

Answer (score 0):

Use these functions:

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;

    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = escape(name) + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return unescape(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

**Edit** Updated sample to load cookie on load

http://jsfiddle.net/aZXMr/3/

Comment: its not storing cookies.. when I refresh the page it removes all the appended HTML..

thanks for you help!

Comment: Updated the example to load a cookie on page load... Also, you shouldn't be using cookies to save html...  Cookies should be used as identifiers only (i.e. this cookie belongs to this user, etc...). This is because cookies have a limit of how much they can store (it's about 4KB of data)...

Comment: yeah! it can only store a limited data size... but I have to store for the time being...

unfortunately also this time above code is not working... many thanks for your time...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), like this:

```
$('#add').on('click', function(){
    var inputHTML = $('#inputName').val();
    $('<li>'+inputHTML+'</li>').appendTo('#inputBox > ul');

    var myData = localStorage.cookieData ? JSON.parse(localStorage.cookieData) : new Array();
    myData.push(inputHTML);
    localStorage.cookieData = JSON.stringify(myData);

    console.log(myData);
})
```

Comment: can you please provide fiddle URL storing cookies... thanks in advance